# Identify df column name_pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. In the first row of df1 column 'attribute', I have a value like 'color'. In df2 I have a column named 'color' in this case. Basically the column from df2 takes as name, the value from df1 column attribute.

But the name of this column is dynamic meaning, I may have another attribute value in df1 like 'size' so that the name of df2 column becomes 'size'.
I need to access in df2 this column for concatenation. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of the code.

Comment: You can do df1.pivot and make df1 values as columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the attributes in `df1` are strings, you can simply use the standard syntax:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'attribute': ['color', 'size', 'shape']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue', 'red'],
                    'size': [1, 10],
                    'shape': ['a', 'b']})

df2[df1.attribute[0]]
```

```
0    blue
1     red
Name: color, dtype: object
```

You can use this in conjunction with concatenation, e.g.

```py
for i in range(3):
    print((df1.attribute[i] 
           + ' ' 
           + df2[df1.attribute[i]].astype(str)).values)
```

```
['color blue' 'color red']
['size 1' 'size 10']
['shape a' 'shape b']
```

Comment: thank you but how can I use this in a concatenation as df2['col1'].astype(str) +/concatenated with the value from df2 column color? How can I access the name of that column?

Comment: I've added another example to the answer.

Comment: than you so much!